# Crash when child widgets depend on a parent's dependency

Tags: c++, qt

```
class MyMainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
private:
  SomeDependency someDependency;
}

class SomeWidget : public QWidget
{
public: 
  ~SomeWidget()
  {
    // Use someDependency by getting it from MyMainWindow (or having MyMainWindow pass it in)
  }
}

MyMainWindow::MyMainWindow(QWidget* parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
{
  SomeWidget* someWidget = new SomeWidget(this);
}
```

I'm running into a problem with this pattern. `MyMainWindow` owns `SomeDependency`. `MyMainWindow` creates a new `SomeWidget` on the heap and gives it a parent `this`.

The destructor of `SomeWidget` needs to call `SomeDependency` to do something (say... unregister itself from the dependency when it's dying). This works fine when widgets go away normally.

When the app is killed, however, there's a weird problem. The `MyMainWindow` destructor is called first. It will clean up `SomeDependency`. Next, the `QMainWindow` destructor is called. This will clean up all of its children. It starts deleting its children, which causes `SomeWidget` to get destroyed. The `SomeWidget::~SomeWidget()` then calls `SomeDependency`... but it's been destroyed, so the app crashes.

How can I play by the Qt parent/child memory lifetime rules, but have children get their dependencies from `MyMainWindow`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to do what you should have been doing all along: not allocate child widgets on the heap, unless they need to be dynamically created. C++ has well-defined semantics: `m_widget` will be destroyed before `m_dependency`.

```
class MyMainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  SomeDependency m_dependency;
  SomeWidget m_widget;
};
```

It is perfectly fine for `m_widget` to have `MyMainWindow` as a parent.

Alternatively, if the widget needs to be dynamically created for some reason:

```
class MyMainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  SomeDependency m_dependency;
  QScopedPointer<SomeWidget> m_widget;
};
```

Finally, `SomeWidget` could share ownership of `SomeDependency`:

```
class MyMainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  QSharedPointer<SomeDependency> m_dependency;
  QScopedPointer<SomeWidget> m_widget { m_dependency };
};

class SomeWidget : public QWidget {
  QSharedPointer<SomeDependency> m_dependency;
public:
  SomeWidget(QScopedPointer<SomeDependency> dep, QWidget * parent = 0) :
    m_dependency(dep) {
    ...
  }
};
```

Side note: make sure you really need a `QMainWindow`. Don't use it if a `QDialog` will do.